# Facebook Graph token hell

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I often fetch Facebook photos to fly into websites for clients. They always work for a while, then suddenly stops working.

I have read on stack that it's a token issue, but what I don't understand is how my JSON call could ever work to begin with, given that I never had any code to get a token. A JSON call like this works for a week or so then stops working. And, it doesn't matter that the photos albums in question are set to "public" by the owner.

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/616894958361877/photos?limit=100&callback=?', function(json) {
    $.each(json.data, function(i, photo) {
        $('<li></li>').append('<span class="thumb" style="background: url(' + ((photo.images[1]) ? photo.images[1].source : '') + ') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"><a href=' + ((photo.images[0]) ? photo.images[0].source : '') + ' rel="gallery"></a></span>').appendTo('#timeline');
    });
});
```

Can someone give me some example code on how to **permanently** fix this? I get links to the facebook graph help pages explaining tokens and permissions but I simply don't understand how to apply it to my situation. Most of it refers to apps which is not my situation.

Comment: Start by using an access token

Comment: _“Most of it refers to apps which is not my situation”_ – you _need_ to use an app, because without app, no access token, and without access token, no more data from the API (that is new with API v2). If you want to do this client-side, then you will need to make user login to your app, so that you can use their user access token. Your alternative is to request the data server-side; then you can use your app access token to get publicly available data. (The app access token does __never__ belong in client-side code.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were making calls with no Access Token at all, to data that's publicly visible on Facebook.com

v1.0 of Facebook's Graph API was deprecated in April 2014 and scheduled for removal after 2015-04-30 - one of the changes between v1.0 and v2.0 was that in v2.0 all calls require an Access Token - the deprecation of v1.0 was phased and one of the last things to be removed was the ability to make tokenless calls - it's possible that's why you didn't notice this until recently

More info on the changelog here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0 - under "Changes from v1.0 to v2.0"

You'll need to rewrite your app to make its API calls using an access token from a user who can see the content you're trying to create, or (possibly) using your app's access token (and given you had no token at all, you may also need to create an app ID for that purpose)

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that since May 1, it is **necessary** to create an app and then generate a token and use it in my JSON call URL.

So this:

```
 $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/616894958361877/photos?limit=100&callback=?
```

Became this:

```
 $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/616894958361877/photos?access_token=123456789123456789|ajdkajdlajfldkeieflejejf&limit=100&callback=?
```

I've replaced my actual token with random numbers, but it's basically a giant string of numbers and letters with a pipe in the middle.

For me the confusing part was needing an "app" when I'm not using a mobile device. I also didn't realize that Facebook had actually deprecated the old methond.

Creating an app is simple... go here and follow the steps:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Leave the "NameSpace" field blank... not sure what that is exactly and it's not required.

Generating the token string took a few more steps which a friend from work walked me through... I can't remember off the top of my head, but once you get the string and insert it into your JSON call, it will definitely work.

The REASON for this is so when Facebook receives a data request from some random website, the request comes with a built-in ID so Facebook knows who is asking for the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need an App Access Token.

Go to http://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and create an app for the client's Facebook page. When you're presented with the options, select the "Website" type of app. You can skip the configuration option using the "Skip and Create App ID" button in the top right corner.

Give it a Display Name, don't worry about the Namespace, and give it a applicable category.

Once the app is created, go to "Tools & Support" > "Access Token Tool" in the top menu.

You should see an App Token listed in green text. Copy that into your JSON call, and it should work.

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/616894958361877/photos?access_token=PASTE_APP_TOKEN_HERE&limit=100&callback=?', function(json) {
$.each(json.data, function(i, photo) {
    $('<li></li>').append('<span class="thumb" style="background: url(' + ((photo.images[1]) ? photo.images[1].source : '') + ') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;"><a href=' + ((photo.images[0]) ? photo.images[0].source : '') + ' rel="gallery"></a></span>').appendTo('#timeline');
});
```

});